# Visual Studio 2015 - The Specified Account Already Exists for Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to install Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 on Windows 7 with Xamarin. When the installer completes, I get an error about Xamarin: "The specified account already exists".

[image: 1]

Comment: With professional and above you new get a xamarin license included. If you have an active license through Xamarin perhaps there is a conflict with registering the license under the same email.

Comment: I do have a license in 2013 registered on my system. Perhaps I should uninstall 2013 and see if that helps things.

Comment: When I spoke with our account rep and he was informed we had VS Professional or Enterprise licenses he said that he was just going to cancel our Xamarin License and we should go into the MSDN subscription to active Xamarin from within our Visual Studio. Which is why I am guessing your licensed VS is conflicting with your Xamarin.com license potentially.

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for this site. SO is for programming questions. You should try the Xamarin forums if you do not have a service contract for Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely uninstalled Xamarin and Xamarin Studio and then ran repair from the VS installer and I no longer get the Xamarin account message.